# Do I need a visitor visa for Guatemala if I am traveling through El Salvador? (Indian Citizen)

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, guatemala, el-salvador

I am an Indian passport holder. I am going to El Salvador this year in December. I will be spending 10 days in El Salvador and 5 days in Guatemala. My flight path is India - US - El Salvador.

I know I need a transit visa for the US. I don't need a visitor visa for El Salvador because Indian Passport holders are allowed to visit this country for 90 days without visa.

[According to the Indian embassy in Guatemala](http://www.indemguatemala.org/traveling-to-guatemala/):

> El Salvador is part of the CA-4 agreement which means visitors can visit Guatemala without permission.

Can I visit Guatemala from El Salvador without a visum for Guatemala?
I will be traveling from El Salvador to Guatemala by land.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=IN&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=GT&selDest=Guatemala&selTrans=Use%20ctrl-key%20to%20select%20or%20deselect%20transit%20point%28s%29%20above&user=OLYMPIC&subuser=OLYMPICB2C), the database used by airlines:

> Visa required, **except** for Passengers with a valid visa issued
>   by Canada, the **USA** or a Schengen Member State for a maximum stay of 90 days

In case of ignorant border officials (not unlikely), print [this government page in Spanish](http://www.minex.gob.gt/Visor_Pagina.aspx?PaginaID=21), and underline with a pen the following text, next to "India" (number 26):

> nacionales Hindúes que cuenten con una visa vigente de los Estados Unidos de América, Canadá o Schengen no necesitan visa para ingresar a territorio guatemalteco.

**Moreover**, the CA-4 agreement means that after entering one of the countries, you can travel by land to the others freely regardless of visa requirements. Meaning, your El Salvadorian stamp is also valid for Guatemala, and you won't get stamped at the El Salvadorian-Guatemalan border.

I have heard, however, that many officers think this only applies to CA-4 citizens, so I'd still recommend bringing the printout saying that Indians with a valid US visa don't need a visa to visit Guatemala at all.

So no, you do **not** Need a visa

Comment: I am appling for a Trasit visa of the US. is it enough to enter Guatemala? what if i have a direct flight from India to El salvador?

Comment: @Terro Any unexpired US visa is fine, and it doesn't matter how you're travelling

Comment: Indian citizens do not need a visa to enter el salvador. el salvador is one of C-4 countries that provides visa free access to indians. Is it fine if i take a direct flight to el-salvador and then to guatemala? (without any visa)

Comment: @Terro I know. For El Salvador Indians don't Need a visa, and for Guatemala, Indians with a valid US visa don't Need a visa. The CA-4 agreement (no border control) only applies when travelling by land, but because you have a valid US visa, flying is OK too

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I am traveling by land from salvador to GT and from your comment now its clear that I dont need any visa only stamp of the salvador on my passport is required. Am i understanding it right?

Comment: @Terro Correct.

Comment: Crazydre : Thank you so much for your help . I will accept your answer and give you the bounty soon.