# Border crossing in CA-4 countries (Guatemala, Honduras) for foreigners

Tags: visas, belarus, central-america, guatemala, honduras

Belarus citizens don't need a visa for Honduras but need a visa for Guatemala. I found this:

> CA-4 agreement means that after entering one of the countries, you can
>   travel by land to the others freely regardless of visa requirements

Does it mean that if Belarus citizen enters Honduras by plane, he can visit Guatemala (or Salvador) by land from Honduras without CA-4 visa?
Thank you!

Comment: Where did the quoted language come from?

Comment: This is from another travel stackexchange answer: https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/100336/94316

Comment: That is indeed what the Answer says, but I don't know if it's correct. The Wikipedia page on the CA-4 agreement https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_America-4_Border_Control_Agreement says the same, but my Spanish isn't good enough to decipher the CA-4 original text in Spanish https://reddhmigrantes.files.wordpress.com/2014/06/acuerdo-regional-ca4.pdf.

Comment: All information I can find indicate that Belarus citizens need a visa to enter Honduras as well.

Comment: I agree with @Tor-EinarJarnbjo, the OP's statement of not needing a visa is either incorrect or incomplete. Timatic (via OlympicAir) cms.olympicair.com/timatic/webdocsI/spdbmainv.html indicates that as to a citizen of Belarus heading for Honduras: "Visa required, except for Nationals of Belarus with a visa valid for at least 6 months on arrival, issued by Canada, the USA or a Schengen Member State."

Comment: @David , there is 

`* Nicaragua y Honduras: Darán trato de Categoría "A" a los portadores de pasaportes ordinarios.`

for Belarus in document

`Listado para fines de exención y obligatoriedad de visas, homologado por
los países del CA-4 (Guatemala, El Salvador, Honduras y Nicaragua).`

Comment: @Khalimonka I said that my Spanish was insufficient to understand the underlying CA-4 document. The language you quote (run through Google Translate) seems to say your conclusion is correct. On the other hand, given that airlines consistently rely on Timatic, it's odd that Timatic gives a different result. Let us know how it works out.

Answer (score 2):

The CA-4 agreement classifies nationalities in three categories: A, B, C.

[image: CA-4 Visa Categories]

Nicaragua and Honduras recognize Belarus citizens as "A" citizens, who are visa exempt:

[image: CA-4 Nationalities List]

.. which means that with an ordinary Belarus passport you can enter both Honduras and Nicaragua with no visa.

When you've entered the CA-4 through one of the above two countries that consider you an A citizen, can you move freely to other CA-4 countries, with a Belarus passport? No.

You can move freely between Honduras and Nicaragua, but in order to travel to Guatemala or El Salvador, you need to obtain a visa:

[image: Cuando uno de los Estados Parte, beneficie a un país clasificado en la “categoría B” a “Categoría A”; y su nacionalidad debe movilizarse en la región, que requiere visa, podrá solicitarla en el Consulado respectivo.]

When one of the CA-4 countries grants a nationality an "A" category, which is otherwise considered by the CA-4 as a "B" category, and this national needs to move in the CA-4 region, to a country that requires a visa, the national will be able to apply for a Visa at the respective consulate.

[Source: https://igm.gob.gt/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/MANUAL-CA4-Unificado.pdf](https://igm.gob.gt/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/MANUAL-CA4-Unificado.pdf)